# Restangular: setRequestSuffix() not setting global suffix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I am using Restangular and want to setup suffix for my requests. When I am doing it locally just before making the request in my services it's working, but I want to setup it globally.

The problem is that is not working when I am setting it in the .config. The baseUrl is working but the suffix is still missing. Any ideas what I am doing incorrect?

```
angular.module('app').config(function(RestangularProvider) {
    RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl("/api");

    // This function is used to map the JSON data to something Restangular
    // expects for the paginated results
    RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation, what, url) {
        if (operation === "getList" && response.results) {
            // Use results as the return type, and save the result metadata
            // in _resultmeta
            var newResponse = response.results;
            newResponse._resultmeta = {
                "count": response.count,
                "next": response.next,
                "previous": response.previous
            };
            return newResponse;
        }

        return response;
    });

    //RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('peshooo');
    RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('.json');
});
```